# QStringList creation in place for parameter passing

Tags: c++, qt, qstringlist

I have a function that gets a `QStringList` as a parameter.
The `QStringList` is created in place for parameter passing. Two possibilities come to my mind for this:

```
myFunction(QStringList() << myQString); // possibility 1
myFunction(QStringList { myQString }); // possibility 2
```

Which possibility is more performant?

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to write a benchmark and measure. I would expect the difference, if any at all, to be immeasurably small.

Comment: Talking about performace without measurements isn't usually a good idea. However, in this case the first variant is most likely the same or slower since you're constructing an empty list and then appending an element. The second option constructs the list with the element already in place.

Comment: It probably does not really matter unless the code is executed hundreds of thousands of times so that the small savings per call could make a difference. In my code I have used both but now write the 2nd form for all new usages.

Comment: I appreciate your care about details. IMHO, this is a good habit when writing code in C++ as the language / compiler is quite unforgiving. Btw. concerning containers, the more common mistake is to pass them unnecessarily by value to a function instead of by const reference but this is related to how the function itself is declared/defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the benchmark:

```cpp
#define ct_Benchmark(EXPR, repeat){\
    int repeated = repeat;\
    qint64 initialTime = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();\
    qint64 totalTime   = initialTime;\
    EXPR;\
    initialTime = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - initialTime;\
    for ( int ___i_ = 0; ___i_ < repeated; ___i_++) {\
        EXPR;\
    }\
    totalTime = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - totalTime;\
    qreal averageTime = qreal( totalTime / repeated );\
    const QString expression(#EXPR);\
    const QString iterations(" Cycles: " + QString::number( repeated    ) );\
    const QString initial   ("Initial: " + QString::number( initialTime ) );\
    const QString total     ("  Total: " + QString::number( totalTime   ) );\
    const QString average   ("Average: " + QString::number( averageTime, 'g', 24 ) );\
    ct_Info(expression, iterations, initial, total, average);\
}
```

```
    QString sneed("'s feed & seed. Formerly chucks.");
    ct_Benchmark( QStringList{ sneed }, 1000000 );
    ct_Benchmark( QStringList( QStringList() << sneed ), 1000000 );
```

---

### Debug

```cpp
Info /home/anon/Programming/QtConsoleDesigner/QtSandbox/src/sandbox.cpp:57
int main(int, char**)

QString expression
"QStringList( QStringList() << sneed )"

QString iterations
" Cycles: 10000000"

QString initial
"Initial: 0"

QString total
"  Total: 3461"

QString average
"Average: 0"
```

```cpp
Info /home/anon/Programming/QtConsoleDesigner/QtSandbox/src/sandbox.cpp:56
int main(int, char**)

QString expression
"QStringList{ sneed }"

QString iterations
" Cycles: 10000000"

QString initial
"Initial: 0"

QString total
"  Total: 2094"

QString average
"Average: 0"
```

---

### Release:

```cpp
Info /home/anon/Programming/QtConsoleDesigner/QtSandbox/src/sandbox.cpp:57
int main(int, char**)

QString expression
"QStringList( QStringList() << sneed )"

QString iterations
" Cycles: 10000000"

QString initial
"Initial: 0"

QString total
"  Total: 545"

QString average
"Average: 0"
```

```cpp
Info /home/anon/Programming/QtConsoleDesigner/QtSandbox/src/sandbox.cpp:56
int main(int, char**)

QString expression
"QStringList{ sneed }"

QString iterations
" Cycles: 10000000"

QString initial
"Initial: 0"

QString total
"  Total: 379"

QString average
"Average: 0"
```

Compiled using GCC.
Possibility 1 `QStringList{ sneed }` is about a third faster.